# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'useful_clip' issue

Tags: python

I coded a module code but it gives me an error
moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'useful_clip' despite installing pip module
so what is the solution of this issue bug?
here s what I coded:

```
import useful_clip 
 

print(useful_tool.roll_dice(10))
```

the file project:

```
import random  

feet_in_mile=1000 
meters_in_kilometers=1400
beatles=['ahab','John travolta','usain bolt','sonic the hedhog','XXRL8 ','Shazam' ]

def get_file_ext(filename):  
    return filename[filename.index('.')+ 1:]

def roll_dice(num):
    return random.randint(1,num)
```

Comment: shouldn't that be ```import useful_tool```?

Comment: despite installing pip what should I do

Comment: You created this module? and this is in your current directory?

Comment: I already created

Comment: import useful_tools as ut


print(useful_tools as ut.function(10))   is it correct